# How I can find all unused import programmatically?

Tags: java, reverse-engineering, static-analysis

In my case there are two reason for doing that:

- Sometimes people by mistake import classes  which present in macbooks JDKs but absent in Linux. That causes build to fail on ci servers which are Linux based boxes. I doesn’t happen frequently, but when it does happened I'm thinking that there should be some smarter way to find out that earlier.
- Unused imports trigger warning in IDE/code analysis. From time to time somebody need to spend time on cleaning up this stuff. Even if its just single right click in IDE you still need to commit your changes and make sure everything alright on build.

I'm curious if there is any way to find unused imports programmatically (lets say from unit test) ***and*** fail locally if there are any.

Maybe failing a build because of unused import sounds harsh, but if it saves time for team overall it makes sens to do so (would love to hear opinion on that as well).

**UPDATE**:

I followed [yegor256](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187141/yegor256) suggestion and incorporated Checkstyle task with initially small subset of [Sun Code Conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22961733/oracle-java-code-conventions) (unused imports is one of them) and made it break a build if violations found.

After one week of trial we've got zero unused imports in our codebase and surprisingly zero complaints about this rule (by the way, Checkstyle is really fast: analyzing ~100KLoc taking less than one second).

As for using IDE for such analysis: yes, it good choice, but having this kind of checks run as part of automated build is better.

Comment: Just as an aside, most any modern IDE has a "Fix Imports" style of command that cleans up the imports.

Comment: Note that this will not enforce the checks whereas integrating in the build tool does that and you'll not have one single commit with unused input.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called [static code analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis). [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) can help you. If you're using Maven, this plugin will do the automation for you: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/

You can also take a look at [qulice.com](http://www.qulice.com) (I'm one of its developers), which integrates a few static analysis tools and pre-configures them (incl. Checkstyle, PMD, FindBugs).

Comment: yes, your CI build script can invoke Checkstyle, PMD or FindBugs plugins. The same build script can be run in the local machines to detect these issues and make sure they are fixed before the next check in.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using eclipse IDE or IntelliJ IDEA, you can configure them to

1a. organize imports / remove unused imports on save or before commit (see cleanup preferences)

1b. switch the "unused imports" warning to an error (see error settings)

2a. configure a jre which does not include com.* stuff

2b. configure the warning of proprietary api usage from the jre to be an error

You might still want to check that on the build server, though. In this case the more complicated stuff like configuring CheckStyle would still be necessary.

Comment: We're using both Eclipse and IntellIJ. cleanup preferences - are they made at project level or at IDE level? I'm asking because project settings are stored in mercurial, but IDE settings are unique to each developer.

Comment: It has been a while since I used IDEA, not sure there. In eclipse you can override global settings with project specific settings. So if you want to share them it's fine to specify them on project level.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm curious if there is any way to find unused imports programmatically (lets say from unit test) and fail build locally if there are any.

I use IntelliJ to organise imports, this removes all the unused imports. You can do this with one hot key from the top of you code base to correct all the imports. (It also has over 700 other types of static checks and fixes)

> Maybe failing a build because of unused import sounds harsh, but if it saves time for team overall it makes sens to do so (would love to hear opinion on that as well).

I have IntelliJ check in code which formatted and with imports organised so the issue never arises in the first place. ;)

Comment: Thanks Peter. Christian suggested the same solution. In my case we have team of 20+ working on the same codebase and supporting the same code standards is not possible(for myself including) unless they are at project level (project settings under source control) or make build fail.

Comment: I don't see how making the build fail without fixing the problem will help. At some point the code has to be fixed anyway. I would make it automatic.

Comment: Making the build fail without fixing the problem **will** help, if used as a "red flag" in a continuous integration mechanism

Comment: @Peter, what I mean is that once all unused import are removed then mechanism for failing build could be introduced to avoid regression.

Comment: @yegor256, +1. I think we're on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

In Computer Science the name given to such a process of analyzing the code without executing is known as `static code analysis`.

Try using an IDE, I am using Eclipse, which marks all the Unused imports and Unused Variables or methods in with a Yellow color underline....

Answer (score 0):

Aren't these unrelated questions? If you import classes only present in the local JDK, these imports *are* used (just unsatisfied). For either problem, I recommend solving it in the IDE so the problem will be detected when code is written, rather than prior to checkin (the earlier the detection, the easier the fix ...).

In eclipse, you could prevent unsatisfied imports with [access rules](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53736.html), and automatically fix imports whenever a source file is saved by enabling the appropriate [save action](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/editor/ref-preferences-save-actions.htm). If you check these settings into version control, you can easily share them with the team.

Answer (score 0):

I see lot of comments in same way that use this IDE or that IDE.  But all my friends try to understand the difference.  Doing something programmatically is different and using IDE is different.

If I want a process to be programmatic then suggestion of IDE is not useful.  It might be possible some one is asking this question because he is building complete process and this step is part of it.  How opening IDE would help him on different machines and OS where CI is working?

I too building one tool on similar lines.  I achieved it up to some level but it programmatically open IDE and close it automatically and fixes source code too.  But opening same in Linux might be a question for me.

Understanding some one's view before answering is really very important.

Comment: Your comment is completely correct - but it should be a comment, not an answer, as it does not answer (or attempt to answer) the question.  (I do agree with you though!)