# Oracle Java code conventions

Tags: java, coding-style

Does someone know where I can find the document by Oracle which describes Java code conventions?

This URL is not available anymore, for that reason I created new question for this topic.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

Comment: This is also asked on the [oracle forums](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3544233), but no answers.

Comment: If you know better option to do this I will follow to that with pleasure. @eis I've seen the oracle forums as well and I thought all developers are here and it could be helpful for everyone. This was the purpose.

Comment: Yes, I was only referencing the question to indicate that other people are searching for an answer to this as well.

Comment: note to future close voters: I think this falls into [Shog9's "canonical source" exception](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/165597?m=43207688#43207688).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

One option is to use wayback machine, which [seems to contain the document](http://web.archive.org/web/20140222045352/http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) ([here's direct link to pdf version](http://web.archive.org/web/20140228225807/http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)). However I would also be interested to find out what Oracle did with it and do they intend to get rid of it.

There's a [discussion on Oracle forums](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3544233) about this being raised to OTN support, but no response is mentioned.

---

Update on 17.6.2014: There's now a [forum posting](https://community.oracle.com/message/12472357#12472357) added to the site explaining the following:

> Those Java Code Conventions were written in 1999 and have not been
>   maintained since.
>
> The information might not be up to date; links within the documents
>   might not work.    That is why the pages were removed.  Unfortunately
>   there are other sites that point to that document which were not
>   updated.
>
> To avoid confusions we have re-posted the original document –with an
>   appropriate disclaimer about the information not being up to date-
>   while we clean up those other sites.
>
> Try [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-135089.html)

And indeed, seems the page has been restored.

Answer (score 12):

The required basis is here:

Google:

- https://github.com/google/styleguide
- https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html

Oracle:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf

Spring:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Code-Style
- https://github.com/47deg/coding-guidelines/tree/master/java/spring

More advanced stuff, related to logical structures in the book on page https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/ and the book "Clean Code"

---

Answer (score 3):

I think that document is dated. SEI has published [the latest standards](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/Java+Coding+Guidelines) - cool and really good.

Comment: Does SEI define the rules for Oracle or it is different one?

Comment: That link is to SEI CERT's _secure_ coding guidelines, while also very important IMHO they are not general-purpose coding style guidelines. Their new location seems to be https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java

Answer (score 0):

The document could be found at:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf

Comment: If you will check the link from the previous answer it contains the same link which you've added ;)

Answer (score 0):

The old document seems to be available as HTML too http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Answer (score 0):

I answer this only because the Oracle docs linked here seem to have last been edited in 1997 and this Oracle doc was last edited in April 20, 1999. It has the appropriate disclaimer of no longer being updated.
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-fileorganization.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30877706)