# Access class methods from an object that is that class

Tags: java

I am trying to make an checkFalse method where i take Object as an argument. I now want to check if that Object is the same type as this.getClass(). If it is of the same type, i now want to cast the Object to that class in order to access the methods of that object class!

For example, how can i access the SomeMethod from that f object? I am trying to convert the object F to the class testMain.

Error: Cannot be cast to testMain

```
class testMain implements testest
{

}

interface testest
{
    public default boolean SomeMethod()
    {

    }

    public default boolean checkFalse(Object f) throws  ClassCastException
    {
        try 
        {
            f = this.getClass();
        } 
        catch (ClassCastException exception) 
        {
            throw exception;
        }
        f = (testMain)f; //Here. How do i turn this object to the    class testMain so that i can access that objects methods? For example, how can i access the SomeMethod through this f object?
     }
}
```

Comment: I've removed the c# code since this is clearly a Java question.

Comment: Okay sure. Included c# because they are almost identical. But fair enough!

Comment: You have to cast to `testest` (not `testMain`). By the way: Stick to the [Java code conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22961733/oracle-java-code-conventions), and write class and interface names in `CamelCase`.

Comment: I tried that but i get the same error only now it says "Cannot be cast to testtest"

Comment: Casting to `testest` gives you the error "cannot be cast to Queue" ???

Comment: Actually. If i remove the try & catch block and change to cast to testtest i get no errors. But i still cant access the methods inside :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public default boolean checkFalse(Object f) {
    if(f instanceof testest) {
        ((testest)f).someMethod();
    } else
        throw new RuntimeException();
}
```