# The program runs, but the second loops ends regardless of input

Tags: java, loops

I am really new to java and I am having trouble finding what I did wrong here, This program is to ask for sales amounts and then get the average regardless of the number of sales, that part seems to work fine. The issue when it asks for the shipping costs, it accepts the first input but regardless of if you reply with y or n it ends, and the program ends, did I just miss something really obvious here? (also I tried to look at how other people made it more readable and I am sorry I do not know what I am doing so sorry.)

tried altering it, but then it just made errors I didn't know how to resolve myself as I am new and this is my first attempt at learning java, my school requires us to use NetBeans (10.0 in my case)

```java
import java.util.*;

public class JavaApplication3
{   //these ones are the attributes.      private String Sales1,2,3;
    public static boolean b_repeat = true;
    private double Sales1;
    private double Sales2;
    private double Sales3;

    //this is a constructor of 2 parameters for Cales class.
    public JavaApplication3(double Sales1, double Sales2, double Sales3)
    {
        this.Sales1 = Sales1;
        this.Sales2 = Sales2;
        this.Sales3 = Sales3;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        double avg = computeAverageSales();
        System.out.println(" Average of Sales :" + avg);
        if (avg > 200) {
            System.out.println(" Product has produced a significant amount of revenue!");
        }
        double chr = computeShippingCharges();
        System.out.println(" Total shipping charge :" + chr);
    }

    public static double computeAverageSales()
    {
        double avgSales, salesIn, total = 0;
        int cnt = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.println("Input Sales");
            double sales = sc.nextDouble();
            total = total + sales;
            cnt++;
            System.out.println("Would you like to keep adding Sales? (y/n)");

            String repeatLoop = sc.next();
            if (repeatLoop.toLowerCase().equals("n"))
                b_repeat = false;
        } while (b_repeat);

        System.out.println(); //Space seperator
        avgSales = total / cnt;
        return (avgSales);
    }

    public static double computeShippingCharges()
    {
        double avgShipping, shippingIn, total = 0;
        int cnt = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.println("Input Shipping cost");
            double shipping = sc.nextDouble();
            total = total + shipping;
            cnt++;
            System.out.println("Would you like to keep adding Shipping costs? (y/n)");

            String repeatLoop = sc.next();
            if (repeatLoop.toLowerCase().equals("n"))
                b_repeat = false;
        } while (b_repeat);

        System.out.println(); //Space seperator
        avgShipping = total;
        return (avgShipping);

    }

    public double getSales1()
    {
        return this.Sales1;
    }

    public void setSales1(double sales)
    {
        this.Sales1 = sales;
    }

    public double getSales2()
    {
        return this.Sales2;
    }

    public void setSales2(double sales)
    {
        this.Sales2 = sales;
    }

    public double getSales3()
    {
        return this.Sales3;
    }

    public void setSales3(double sales)
    {
        this.Sales3 = sales;
    }
}
```

it should accept any amount of sales or shipping inputs but the shipping will only allow one input regardless of what you respond to the

System.out.println("Would you like to keep adding Shipping costs? (y/n)");

with, so that is my issue

Comment: you really should work on correcting the indentation before posting the code... that is not very readable

Comment: apologies,  I will look at what other people post, never used this before so my bad

Comment: also have a look at Java Code Convention, links in that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22967234/85421) (and other answers to that same question) it is old (1999) but Naming convention is still used (e.g. field/variable names start with lowercase; camel-case `b_repeat` is not very java-like)

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, the variable `b_repeat` is defined outside the methods that are using it and is reused every time. So, the first time you call either of `computeAverageSales` or `computeShippingCharges`, it works correctly, but the next time `b_repeat` is already set to false by a previous call. Try moving `boolean b_repeat = true;` into each function and see what happens.

Comment: sounds like this might work, I will try this when I return from work, much appreciated :)

Comment: just to complement: it would be sufficient to do `b_repeat = true` before starting each loop, but, eldar's suggestion is better:  1-you should strive to declare the variables in the *tightest* (not always) block they are used; 2-logically `b_repeat` is not part of the class, not holding any class *information*, should not be  a class field.